# MYSQL LOCAL INFILE command server wants to read - ExpressJS, Mysql2

Tags: mysql, express, web, mysql2

I am trying to import a CSV programmatically into my web app, and when I make an SQL request I am met with this error

Error: As a result of LOCAL INFILE command server wants to read path/to/myfile.csv file, but as of v2.0 you must provide streamFactory option returning ReadStream.

I have tried adding things to the config however I cannot seem to get this working
Code:

```js
async function query(sql){
    console.log("querying")
    const conn = await mysql.createConnection(config.db)
    conn.on("error", (err)=>console.log(err))
    const [results, ] = await conn.query({
        sql:sql,
        values:[],
    })
    return results
}
```

```js
            query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" +
                 req.file.path +
                "' INTO TABLE jr " +
                " FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','" +
                " LINES TERMINATED BY  '\n'" +
                " IGNORE 1 ROWS;").then(r =>
                console.log("Inserted")
            )`=
```